# Can I win without using Anabolic Steroids?

Tags: the-witcher-2

Apparently, Arm Wrestling in The Witcher 2 is **serious business**. The final "boss" in the arm wrestling chain, if you will, is a circus performer named The Mighty Numa. Skalen Burdon says he cheats, and given that The Mighty Numa's "apprentice" standing next to him is selling a potion of Anabolic Steroids, I'm inclined to believe the dwarf.

Do I have to stoop down to his level to beat him, or is there another way? When I try, The Mighty Numa has a tiny target bar, and moves continuously left, even if the arm wrestling cursor isn't red.

It seems impossible.

Comment: That's a pretty bad apprentice if you're going to sell the competition tools to even the competition.

Comment: I haven't arm wrestled yet -- if you lose, are you permanently screwed? If you can have a rematch, I'd say just try it an see if you can beat him. From what I understand it should always be possible unless the match is fixed in this instance.

Comment: @Matthew - you can do it as long as you have the 100 oren entry wager. I'm inclined to think the match is fixed -- the difficulty is absurd compared to all the other arm wrestling matches up to this point.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After losing, you can call him out for being a cheat, and then get into a fist fight. When you win, he admits to cheating and offers to arm wrestle again without cheating. You'll beat him easily without the steroids.

Comment: I didn't have to have a fist fight with him, but otherwise, this worked.

Comment: Indeed, I was able to use Intimidate rather than a fist fight to get him to do the second match clean.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many times without the steroids but each try was a costly failure. It's very easy once you take them and a lot cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

He can be defeated in arm wrestling the first time, I did it you really need to get lucky trough. I think it is not meant to beat him first time because there is no dialogue about it.

Comment: It's not that hard to beat him on the first trial. The journal entry states the same as when intimidated into not using steroids but there's no paragraph regarding loosing or actual intimidating.